# Decomposing a regression in Stata want to understand how much of the variation is explained by gender

Tags: encoding

want to understand how much of the variation is explained by gender and then gender and teacher specific fixed effects. I was trying to use oaxaca in Stata 16 but cannot figure it out.

I first tried oaxaca testscore i.teacher, by(female) pooled but there is no place for a fixed effect i. regressor.

I then created a bunch of individual variables, e.g., gen teacher1 = teacherid == 1 ... gen teachern = teacherid == n.

oaxaca testscore teacher1 teacher2 teacher3...teachern, by(female) pooled detail(teacher: teacher1 teacher2 ... teachern)

which gave me a "3200 conformability error"

I am open to not using the `oaxaca' command for something else that does a decomposition.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. 
Please  open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to share a [mcve].